# Haxe - mapping a string to a class

Tags: class, dictionary, types, haxe

How should I go about mapping a string to a class in Haxe, and then instantiating it?

```
class Foo{}
class Bar extends Foo{}
class Buzz extends Foo{}

// (...)

var classMap:Map<String, Class<Foo>> = [
    "abc" => Bar,
    "def" => Buzz
];
var myClass:Class<Foo> = classMap["abc"];
var myObj:Foo = new myClass(/* params */);
```

I thought this would work, but it throws `unexpected (` after `myClass`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of storing `Class<T>` in the map and resorting to reflection for instantiation, it's a much nicer pattern to store references to the constructors (using their [function type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-function.html)) as detailed in [this haxe.org blog post](https://haxe.org/blog/codingtips-new/).

```
class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {
    public function new() {}
}
class Buzz extends Foo {
    public function new() {}
}
```

```
var constructors:Map<String, Void->Foo> = [
    "abc" => Bar.new,
    "def" => Buzz.new
];
var construct:Void->Foo = constructors["abc"];
var myObj:Foo = construct();
```

https://try.haxe.org/#49E93

Unlike the `Type.createInstance()` approach, this doesn't allow you to pass arbitrary arguments to the constructors they might not even accept, so it's much more type-safe. It also automatically works with [dead code elimination](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-dce.html) because Haxe sees that the constructors are referenced.

Comment: what if the constructors expect different types of arguments?

Comment: I mean, then the `Map` approach kind of loses its point. Even with `Type.createInstance()`, you'd then have to check the String key to decide which arguments to pass.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Type.createInstance` to create an instance of that class. `new` will only work if you want to directly call the constructor on the Class name itself `new Foo()`

I suggest you do it this way:

```
var myClass:Class<Foo> = classMap["abc"];
var myObj:Foo = Type.createInstance(myClass, [/* params */]);
```

Try it online here: https://try.haxe.org/#3134A